# JQuery DataTables - Prevent sorting on sortable column

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a JQuery Datatable with a checkbox in one of the column headings:

```
<table id="vehTbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        ...
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="someId" onchange="TickAllBoxes()" />
            Publish
        </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

My datatable is initialised like this:

```
var table = $("#vehTbl").dataTable(
    {
        ...
        "aoColumns":
        [
            ...
            {
                "mDataProp": "SomeName",
                "fnRender": somefunction,
                "bUseRendered": false
            },
            ...
        ]
    });
```

So this column is sortable. Now I need to prevent the sort event from being fired when checkbox is clicked (and TickAllBoxes is fired as a result). The sorting should work on the column otherwise.

What could potentially work is to bind a handler to "sort" event of the table and prevent default if caller is "someId" checkbox. I haven't had success in doing so, though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add in this script after your dataTable is initialised, and see?

```
var table = $("#vehTbl").dataTable(
{
    ...
    "aoColumns":
    [
        ...
        {
            "mDataProp": "SomeName",
            "fnRender": somefunction,
            "bUseRendered": false
        },
        ...
    ]
});
// add in this
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
```